# SMTPHandler fails to send logging email with timeout error

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm having an issue using python's `SMTPHandler` to send emails upon errors in my web app, but when I use `smtplib` in a shell instance to see if this is an issue with the server or my own connection, I connect to the server fine and can send mail.

Here is my handler setup:

```
if not app.debug:
    if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
        auth = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
            auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
        secure = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
            secure = ()
        mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
            mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
            fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
            toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='Blog Failure',
            credentials=auth, secure=secure)
        mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
```

I'm triggering errors by breaking a unique constraint in my database  and I get the following stack trace relating to the email being sent:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 387, in getreply
    line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 1016, in emit
    smtp.ehlo()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 441, in ehlo
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 391, in getreply
    + str(e))
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: timed out
```

As I mentioned I have ruled out this being a connection issue on my side or the SMTP server I am using because I have connected to it using flask shell:

```
>>> server = smtplib.SMTP(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],app.config['MAIL_PORT'])
S>>> server.ehlo()
(250, b'smtp.gmail.com at your service, [80.44.155.7]\nSIZE 35882577\n8BITMIME\nSTARTTLS\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8')
>>> server.starttls(context=context)
(220, b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS')
>>> server.ehlo()
(250, b'smtp.gmail.com at your service, [80.44.155.7]\nSIZE 35882577\n8BITMIME\nAUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8')
>>> server.login(app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'],app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
(235, b'2.7.0 Accepted')
```

Does anyone familiar with python's handlers know what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I noticed that SMTPHandler constructor now have a timeout argument which defaults to 1 which is probably not enough to manage a request. try increasing the timeout.

For Example:

```
mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
        mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
        fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
        toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='Blog Failure',
        credentials=auth, secure=secure, timeout=10.0)
```

I could not find what is the measure of timeout (Seconds, milliseconds or something else)